# How to change active header item in Laravel?

Tags: php, html, laravel

So I have a header in site.blade.php and I added an active class so the user can know which page he is in. But, as the header is the same for every page, I don't know how to change the class active from one item to another depending on which page the user is.

Basic demonstration of the header

```
<li class="active"> <a href="{{ url('') }}">Home</a> </li>

<li> <a href="{{ url('blog') }}">Blog</a> </li>
```

The class is that one, but when I go to the blog page, I want to remove class active from home and add it to the blog.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `is()` method like this:

```
<li class="{{Request::is('/')?'active':''}}"> <a href="{{ url('') }}">Home</a> </li>
<li> <a class="{{Request::is('blog')?'active':''}}" href="{{ url('blog') }}">Blog</a> </li>
```

Comment: nice one @Ahmad Atoui.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the $currentPage variable to a view in every controller method, and in the header itself do something like this:

```
<li class="{{ $currentPage=='home' ? 'active' : '' }}"> <a href="{{ url('') }}">Home</a> </li>

<li class="{{ $currentPage=='blog' ? 'active' : '' }}"> <a href="{{ url('blog') }}">Blog</a> </li>
```

Your controller:

```
return view("blog", ["currentPage"=>'blog']); // do the same for home
```

This way ternary operator adds class 'active' only when you are on the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use named routes and set up a helper function.  This will help to keep your navigation clean.

**sample named routes**

```php
Route::get('/','HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/blog','BlogController@index')->name('blog.index');
Route::get('/blog/{blog}','BlogController@show')->name('blog.show');
```

**sample helper function**

```php
if (!function_exists('isActiveRoute'))
{
    /**
     * Asserts active route
     *
     * @param $routes
     * @param string $output
     * @return string
     */
    function isActiveRoute($routes, $output = 'active')
    {
        foreach ((array)$routes as $route) {
            if (Route::currentRouteName() == $route) {
                return $output;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**sample blade navigation**

```php
<li class="{{ isActiveRoute('home') }}"> <a href="{{ route('home') }}">Home</a> </li>
<li class="{{ isActiveRoute('blog.index') }}"><a href="{{ route('blog.index') }}">Blog</a> </li>

// Or pass an array of routes if named accordingly

<li class="{{ isActiveRoute(['blog.index','blog.show']) }}"><a href="{{ route('blog.index') }}">Blog</a> </li>
```